# How to weight loss easily?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

In this question, we will only focus on losing weight by doing exercise, although there are still many ways to lose weight.

Different sports burn different amount of calories.

For example, playing billiards for an hour can burn 102 calories<sup>[[1]](http://calorielab.com/burned/?mo=se&gr=15&ti=sports&q=&wt=150&un=lb&kg=68)</sup>, while playing basketball for 15 minutes can already burn 119 calories <sup>[[1]](http://calorielab.com/burned/?mo=se&gr=15&ti=sports&q=&wt=150&un=lb&kg=68)</sup>, which make weight loss by playing basketball easier, at least from some perspectives.

The exact way to weigh the easiness is by dividing the amount of calories burnt by the time needed, which gives us the easiness index (EI).

For example, fencing for 15 minutes can burn 85 calories, which gets an EI of 85/15.

You will be given a list in this format:

```
[["fencing",15,85],["billiards",60,102],["basketball",15,119]]
```

or other format that you want.

Then, you will output the sports which have the highest EI.

#### TL;DR

Given a list of tuples `[name,value1,value2]` output the `name` where `value2/value1` is the highest.

#### Constraints

- You may **not** produce any real number that is not integer in the process.
- You may **not** use any fraction built-in.

#### Specifications (Specs)

- If there is more than one name that satisfy the result, you may output any non-empty subset of them or any element of them.
- The name will match the regex `/^[a-z]+$/`, meaning that it will only consist of lowercase Latin standard alphabet.
- The list will not be empty.

#### Testcase

Input:

```
[["fencing",15,85],["billiards",60,102],["basketball",15,119]]
```

Output:

```
basketball
```

#### References

1. http://calorielab.com/burned/

Comment: Do we get the list as a String, or an array/list?

Comment: @charredgrass As an array, as is the usual practice of this site.

Comment: Can we choose what order the `[name,value1,value2]` are given in?

Comment: Is it OK if dividing integers in our language produces a fractional type by default?

Comment: 1. yes 2. fraction built-in

Comment: Isn't this [do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/8478)?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, this is an example of "do X without Y".

Comment: 102 cal/h is virtually indistinguishable from your base metabolism

Comment: Do you mean "How to lose weight easily?" not "How to weight loss easily?"..

Comment: @Insane It's an inside joke.

Comment: @LeakyNun Right.. inside jokes on titles.. because the majority of people read it as bad grammar :P

Comment: "If there is more than one name that satisfy the result, you may output any subset of them." Does this mean I can return the empty set?

Comment: @acbabis but if there is just one name that satisfy the result, you can not. Good luck trying to save bytes with that special case

Comment: I was about to flag this as spam

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2, 51 bytes

```python
lambda l:max((10**len(`l`)*a/b,s)for s,b,a in l)[1]
```

Does the obvious thing of finding the entry with the biggest ratio, but sidesteps the prohibition against floats by first multiplying the numerator by a huge input-dependent power of 10 before floor-dividing.

I'll prove this coefficient is big enough to make floor-division act the same difference as non-floor division.

**Claim:** If a<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> > a<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub>, then floor(Na<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub>) > floor(Na<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub>) for any N≥b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>.

**Proof:** Note that a<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub> is a multiple of 1/b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>, so a<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub> > 0 implies that

> a<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub>
> ≥ 1/b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>

Then, multiplying both sides by N,

> Na<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> - Na<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub>
> ≥ N/b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub> ≥ 1

So, since Na<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub> and Na<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub> differ by at least 1, their respective floors are distinct. ∎

Now, note that the product b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub> has digit length at most their total digit length, which is less than the string length of the input. Since the input is in base 10, its suffices to use 10 to the power of its length `` N=10**len(`l`) `` to produce a number with more digits than it, guaranteeing the condition.

Comment: Any chance e.g. `9` might work instead of `10`?

Comment: @Lynn Unfortunately, it fails for huge inputs like `[('y', 10**296+1, 1), ('x', 10**296, 1)]`.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

```
a=>a.sort(([p,q,r],[s,t,u])=>q*u-r*t)[0][0]
```

Or alternatively

```
a=>a.sort((v,w)=>v[1]*w[2]-v[2]*w[1])[0][0]
```

Sort is of course overkill for this, but `reduce` would take 46 bytes:

```
a=>a.reduce((v,w)=>v[1]*w[2]-v[2]*w[1]?v:w)[0]
```

Comment: If u take [p,q,name] u can save 4 bytes`a=>a.sort(([q,r],[t,u])=>q*u-r*t)[0][2]`

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
pG/*&X<)
```

All computed numbers are integer values. First, the product of the denominators is computed (this is an integer). This product is divided by each denominator (which gives an integer too). Each result is then multiplied by the corresponding numerator. This gives an integer value proportional to the original fraction.

Input format is: numeric array with denominators, numeric array with numerators, cell array of strings with sport names:

```
[85, 102, 119]
[15, 60, 15]
{'fencing', 'billiards', 'basketball'}
```

If there are several minimizers the first one is output.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cEcvKiZYPCk&input=Wzg1LCAxMDIsIDExOV0KWzE1LCA2MCwgMTVdCnsnZmVuY2luZycsICdiaWxsaWFyZHMnLCAnYmFza2V0YmFsbCd9)

```
p     % Take first input. Compute the product of its entries
G/    % Divide by first input element-wise
*     % Take second input. Multiply by previous array element-wise
&X<   % Argmax
)     % Take third input. Index into it using previous result. Display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 42 bytes

```
:{bh.}a*g:?z:2aott.
[D:[S:I:J]]tt:D*:I/:S.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OntiaC59YSpnOj96OjJhb3R0LgpbRDpbUzpJOkpdXXR0OkQqOkkvOlMu&input=W1siZmVuY2luZyI6MTU6ODVdOlsiYmlsbGlhcmRzIjo2MDoxMDJdOlsiYmFza2V0YmFsbCI6MTU6MTE5XV0&args=Wg)

`/` above is integer division because both `J*D` and `I` are integers (`D` is a multiple of `I` in fact).

#### Explanation

- Main predicate: `Input = [["string":mins:cals]:...]`

  ```
  :{bh.}a*                Multiply all mins in the Input together
          g:?z            Zip that number with the Input
              :2a         Apply predicate 2 to that zipped list
                 ott.     Sort the list of lists on the values of the first element of
                            sublists, Output is the string of the last sublist
  ```
- Predicate 1:

  ```
  [D:[S:I:J]]             Input = [D:[S:I:J]]
             tt:D*        Multiply J by D
                  :I/     Divide the result by I
                     :S.  Output = [That number:S]
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 18 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⎕⊃⍨(⊢⍳⌈/)⎕×(∧/÷⊢)⎕
```

Prompts for times, then for calories, then for activity names.

`⎕` prompt (for times)

`(∧/÷⊢)` LCM `∧/` of the times divided by `÷` the times `⊢` (so no floats)

`⎕×` prompt (for calories) and multiply by them

`(⊢⍳⌈/)` in that `⊢`, get the position `⍳` of the maximum value `⌈/`

`⎕⊃⍨` prompt (for activities), then pick the *n*th.

Example run:

```
      ⎕⊃⍨(⊢⍳⌈/)⎕×(∧/÷⊢)⎕
⎕:
      15 60 15
⎕:
      85 102 119
⎕:
      'fencing' 'billiards' 'basketball'
basketball
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```python
lambda x:sorted(x,lambda(S,N,D),(s,n,d):N*d-n*D)[0][0]
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 1 byte!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9Fk7pr).

Comment: Nice! I forgot that `sorted` can take a two-input comparator function, I was going to hack that together.

Comment: Seems like it's shorter to unpack `lambda(a,b,c),(d,e,f):b*f-c*e`.

Comment: @xnor Neat! I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>64</s> 62 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\d+
$*
%`\G1
0
1
:$_:
Ts`0p¶`0_`:.+?:
+`(0+) \1
@$1 
O`
!`\w+$
```

Input is one sport per line, with the format `value1 value2 name`. Output is one of the maximal results (if there's a tie it will give the one with the largest `value1` and if those are tied as well if will give the lexicographically larger `name`).

Note that this is *super* slow (for the exact same reasons as [yesterday's Stack Exchange outage](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016)). To make it run in a reasonable amount of time, you can add a `\b` in front of the `(0+)` (which won't affect the way it processes the input at all but severely limits the backtracking of that regex). I've done that in the test link below.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCiVgXEcxCjAKMQo6JF86ClRzYDBwwrZgMF9gOi4rPzoKK2BcYigwKykgXDEKQCQxIApPYAohYFx3KyQ&input=MTUgODUgZmVuY2luZwo2MCAxMDIgYmlsbGlhcmRzCjE1IDg2IGJhc2tldGJhbGw)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```
import Data.List
(n,(x,y))%(m,(a,b))=compare(x*b)$y*a
fst.minimumBy(%)
```

Usage :

```
main=putStr$(fst.minimumBy(%))[("fencing",(15,85)),("billiards",(60,102)),("basketball",(15,119))]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Last/@MaximalBy[#,g=LCM@@First/@#;g#2/#&@@#&]&
```

The order of the tuples should be `{value1,value2,name}`. Returns the full set of all maximal results.

I work around the use of fractions by multiplying the numerator by the LCM of all `value1`s before the division.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 72 bytes

```
e=0;while gets;n=$_.split;f=eval n[2]+"/"+n[1];m,e=n[0],f if f>e;end;p m
```

I really thought this would be shorter...

Input is taken from STDIN in the format of `name time calories`

Oh well, any help to shorten it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
function(v)v[which.max(v[,3]%/%v[,2]),1]
```

Takes input in the form of a data frame with column types of string (it also works with factors), numeric, numeric.

- `%/%` is integer division.

This is my first submission, let me know if it's within the rules.

**Edit:** Turns out you don't need the braces to define a one-line function.

Comment: Might this give the wrong answer if two similar ratios divide to the same integer, e.g. 7/3,9/4?

Comment: My understanding is if they divide to the same integer, you can output any of them, this will output the first in data frame.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 89 bytes

Lambda function:

```
[](auto s,int*a,int*b,int l){int r=--l;while(l--)r=b[l]*a[r]>a[l]*b[r]?l:r;return s[r];};
```

Ungolfed:

```
[](auto s,int*a,int*b,int l)
{
  int r = --l;
  while(l--)
    r = b[l] * a[r] > a[l] * b[r] ? l : r;
  return s[r];
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char* s[] = {"fencing", "billiards", "basketball"};
  int a[] = {15,60,15};
  int b[] = {85,102,119};
  std::cout << [](auto s,int*a,int*b,int l){int r=--l;while(l--)r=b[l]*a[r]>a[l]*b[r]?l:r;return s[r];}(s,a,b,3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 46 bytes

```
s(n,(x,y))=(divMod y x,n)
g =snd.maximum.map s
```

**EDIT:** This solution doesn't work as pointed out by Damien this doesn't solve the problem. I'm searching a nice fix.

Comment: `s(_,(x,y))=divMod y x` is shorter

Comment: `s(n,(x,y))=(divMod y x,n)`
`g=snd.maximum.map s` too..

Comment: But this does not solve the problem as `divMod a b < divMod c d` is not equivalent to `a/b < c/d`. `divMod 19 4 < divMod 55 12` but `19/4 > 55/12`

Comment: Mmmh indeed my solution is quite poor… I'll think of nice fix, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## VBA Excel, 109 bytes

```
Function A(B)
R=1
For I=2 To B.Rows.Count
If B(R,2)*B(I,3)>B(I,2)*B(R,3) Then R=I
Next
A=B(R,1)
End Function
```

Invoke in spreadsheet cell referencing a table of activities and parameters:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
P¹÷*ZQÏ
```

+1 byte to bugfix my divmod approach ([see this comment on another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86056/how-to-weight-loss-easily/195916#comment211685_86245)) by porting [*@LuisMendo*'s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86074/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

Input is similar as his answer: three separated lists, being an integer-list of denominators; an integer-list of nominators; and a string-list of names.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/4NDOw9u1ogIP9///H21oqWNqGssVbaJjaASklBKVdJSSlGIB) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/s5hL6PyDi8HatqMDD/f91/kdbmOoYGhjpGBpaxnJFG5rqmBnoGJoCmUppqXnJmXnpSjpKSZk5OZmJRSnFIHZicXZqSVJiTo4SSL2ljilIsYmOoRFITyJIBVjCwEDHCIiNjY3BPCBHx9gArCQpGagoJTUNSKZnZCrFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
P       # Take the product of the (implicit) input-list of denominators
        #  i.e. [85,102,119] → 1031730
 ¹÷     # (Integer)-divide it by each of the denominators of the first input-list
        #  i.e. 1031730 / [85,102,119] → [12138,10115,8670]
   *    # Multiply each (at the same positions) by the (implicit) input-list of nominators
        #  i.e. [12138,10115,8670] * [15,60,15] → [182070,606900,130050]
    Z   # Get the maximum of this list (without popping the list itself)
        #  i.e. [182070,606900,130050] → [182070,606900,130050] and 606900
     Q  # Check which values are equal to this maximum
        #  i.e. [182070,606900,130050] and 606900 → [0,1,0]
      Ï # Only leave the strings of the (implicit) input-list of names at the truthy indices
        #  i.e. ["fencing","billiards","basketball"] and [0,1,0] → ["billiards"]
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 98 bytes

Used a simpler input format than the example, just like this:

**fencing,15,85,billiards,60,102,basketball,15,119**

```php
$s=explode(",",$argn);for($x=0;$s[$x];$x+=3){if($y<$e=$s[$x+2]/$s[$x+1]){$y=$e;$z=$s[$x];}}echo$z;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLboMwELzzFRbyISgbxZCkakRQb7n2A9ocDFnAxbUt22khUX691JAe6oM9j51ZyaY14@HFhJu6Ansj9RkXMcRAuW1UktfaLmhfsJy6N9qfctovi01yE/WCDgeKxSwvs9P6AdJTcqNDQTGn1@Ivcr9j1Wp6zcfpJfG7ivPoohz60AGEXpOcrNfkVcmBKKzQOW4HEhYTiwa5Jx6dF6oh38K3xLdIVkdSS96MNaoqGJDu4HkHpZBScHt28MQgZRmU3HXoSy7lNJGm@ygoOPMwsWFQa@1mug124OVFyn@BHQPDhXoI26mTRR69FS7AkGfgsetQQcZgz@CTW6E7bv0Uzlj0wb@4q6wwfnJDGMI3z6sCLG1ori9VBynsw/nRxgut3Lg6/gI)

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 opcode, 24 bytes

```
31db 50ac f6e7 92ac f6e3 39d0 ad72 058b  1.P.......9..r..
5cfc 5ab2 58e2 ebc3                      \.Z.X...
        

org 100h
mov si, input
mov cx, 3
call f
mov dx, ax
mov ah, 9
int 0x21
ret
align 2
input:
db 15, 85
dw .fencing
db 60, 102
dw .billiards
db 15, 119
dw .basketball
.fencing db 'fencing$'
.billiards db 'billiards$'
.basketball db 'basketball$'
db 100h+2000-$ dup ? ; Easy to measure size
f:
; bx (record)
; dx (mul result 1)
; ax (result name, pushed)
; ax (mul result 2)
; cx (count)
; si (input array)
xor bx, bx
.L:
push ax
lodsb
mul bh ; nl*bh
xchg ax, dx
lodsb
mul bl ; nh*bl
cmp ax, dx
lodsw
jb .a
mov bx, [si-4]
pop dx
db 0xB2 ; Skip 1 byte
.a:
pop ax
loop .L
ret
```

Comment: `db 0xB2` can be `push ax`

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 128 Bytes

```
String f(List<Object[]>l){return l.stream().max((x,y)->(int)x[2]*1000/(int)x[1]-(int)y[2]*1000/(int)y[1]).get()[0].toString();}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 63 bytes

```
#((last(sort(fn[[x a b][y c d]](-(* b c)(* a d)))%))0)
```